# Changing the tmpdir of MariaDB in debian

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB on my Debian Linux machine and I have a couple of tables with size more than 10GB. When I try to alter the tables, MariaDB creates temp tables and stores them within tmpdir and because of that my tmpdir is running out of space.

To clear the tmpdir I have to restart my Linux machine every time. I created a soft link of tmpdir to other directory but it isn't working. I am just curious if there's an efficient way to resolve this issue?

I checked a few online resources and the solution is to change the location of tmpdir of MariaDB but it isn't working for me. I'd really appreciate if anyone can suggest me a better feasible solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `VARIABLE` `tmpdir` to be some other directory.  Make sure the directory has sufficient privileges for mysqld to access it.  Also restart mysqld after changing the my.cnf to specify it.  Then verify it via `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`

You say you tried to change `tmpdir`; show us the details of changing it.